# Django - 'helpers' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filters

When following the [Custom template tag & filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) tutorial, I get this error:

```
'helpers' is not a valid tag library: Template library helpers not found, tried django.templatetags.helpers,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.helpers,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.helpers
```

I saw a lot of questions about this same issue, but none of the following actions solved it.

Folder structure:

```
container/
  module/
    templatetags/
      __init__.py
      helpers.py
    templates/
      ...
    ... (views, models, ...)
  system/
    ... (urls, settings, ...)
```

In `system/settings.py`, the module is included:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'module',
)
```

My helper source doesn't trigger any syntax or import error from the django shell:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def myhelper(value):
    return value
```

Finally, the template that calls `myhelper` is simply:

```
{% load helpers %}
{{ "hello"|myhelper }}
```

Why doesn't it work ?

Comment: It seems that your system can't find the correct module. Looking at the error message it says: django.templatetags.helpers,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.helpers,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.helpers. It doesn't say anything about module.templatetags. Are you sure that the entry in INSTALLED_APPS is correct? 

Is anyting else working in the module-app when you run it?

Comment: is there any `helpers.pyc` file inside  `templatetags` ??

Comment: @Mikael: yes, I can run other templates from the same module without any problem.

Comment: @PriyankPatel: no sign of such file :S

Comment: that means django can't find `templatetags` inside your module .

Comment: @PriankPatel: so what would be the problem here ?

Comment: Try to run this in django shell: `from django.db.models import get_apps; get_apps()` Do you see your `module` there?

Comment: @DrTyrsa: yep, there is `module.models`.

Comment: Try another name for your template tags. May you already have directory 'helpers' somewhere else.

Comment: @sergzach: That's it ! I don't know why, but modifying the "helper"'s name worked. If someone has an explanation, I'd be please to learn something :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the `sergzach`'s idea, I was able to make my filter work by renaming its file from `helpers.py` to `somethingelse.py`.

---

### Edit

Django has its own [helpers](http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/tags/releases/1.2.5/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py) for generating the admin page. That would be the cause of the naming conflicts.